# Simple Formula to Describe $\zeta$ in One Go

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I was looking around for a simple formula that can describe Riemann Zeta $\zeta$ in one go, at $\mathbb C-\{1\}$, but I couldn't really find one. Could someone help me find one?

I know one way to do this, but it gives a ridiculously complicated formula:

From analytic continuation of 
$$\Xi(s)=\frac1{s-1}-\frac1s+\int_1^\infty(u^{-s/2-1/2}+u^{s/2-1})\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2u}du$$ which holds for $s\in\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\}$, we can deduce a general formula of $\zeta$:
$$\begin{align}
  \zeta(s) &= \pi^{s/2}\frac{\Xi(s)}{\Gamma(s/2)}\\
           &= \pi^{s/2}\left(\frac1{s-1}-\frac1s+\int_1^\infty(u^{-s/2-1/2}+u^{s/2-1})\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2u}du\right)\left(e^{\gamma s/2}\frac s2 \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+\frac s{2n})e^{-s/(2n)}\right)\\
           &=\frac12(\pi e^{\gamma})^{s/2}\left(\frac 1{s-1}+s\int_1^\infty(u^{-s/2-1/2}+u^{s/2-1})\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2u}du\right)\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1+\frac s{2n}}{e^{s/(2n)}}\right)
\end{align}$$
Thus we can write an explicit formula of $\zeta$ that should hold for $\mathbb C-\{1\}$ as following:
$$\zeta(s)=\frac12(\pi e^{\gamma})^{s/2}\left(\frac 1{s-1}+s\int_1^\infty(u^{-s/2-1/2}+u^{s/2-1})\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2u}du\right)\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1+\frac s{2n}}{e^{s/(2n)}}\right)$$

Note that infinite product of $\frac1{\Gamma(s/2)}$ was used to make the expression more direct.

Comment: There are some globally convergent series expressions for zeta on the MathWorld entry.

Comment: This question is probably not supposed to make sense to me. Nonetheless, could you give a more clear notion of what you're trying to find?

Comment: anon That formula looks pretty nice, thank you. However, if possible, I'd like to find an elementary formula that doesn't involve contour integral around a... nontrivial contour.

@Limitless I'm looking for a simple expression of $\zeta$ that converges everywhere at $\mathbb C-\{1\}$.

Comment: @progressiveforest That makes more sense, thank you. I get a slight notion of what you're saying--enough to see where you're going, even if I can't make the journey myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the formula that anon is referring to is
$$
\forall s \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 1 \}: \quad \zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1 - 2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k} (k + 1)^{-s} \right].
$$
I do not see how a contour integral is being used to compute each term. The relevant references are:

- Havil, J. *Gamma: Exploring Euler's Constant*. Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press, 2003.
- Hasse, H. *Ein Summierungsverfahren für die Riemannsche Zeta-Reihe*. Math. Z. 32, 458-464, 1930.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty direct. I think what anon meant though is formula at the bottom of this page:
http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/AnalyticContinuationOfRiemannZetaUsingIntegral.html

Comment: Note that this formula is not actually defined on all $s\in\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}$, but rather all $s$ such that $2^{1-s}\ne1$, due to the division at the outset. The correct statement is $$\zeta(s_0)=\lim_{s\to s_0}\frac1{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk(k + 1)^{-s} \right].$$

Answer (score 3):

There is also an integral formula:

$$ \zeta  \left( s \right) =\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{s-1}+2\,\int _{0}^{
\infty }\!{\frac {\sin \left( s\arctan \left( t \right)  \right) }{
 \left( {t}^{2}+1 \right) ^{s/2} \left( -1+{{\rm e}^{2\,t\pi }}
 \right) }}{dt}
$$
(according to Maple)

Comment: thank you, this is also very nice.