# A convergent-everywhere expression for $\zeta(s)$ for all $1\ne s\in\Bbb C$ with an accessible proof

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

I'm looking for a way to define the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N_0}n^{-s}$ on the whole complex plane, without having to use analytic continuation, or perhaps more accurately, in a way which can be written down as a single formula. (In principle, an analytic continuation can be written down as a formula, but no one ever seems to do it this way, and always end up appealing to drawings in the end.) Any formula will do, even a piecewise one, as long as there is a relatively elementary proof that the expression is equal to $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N_0}n^{-s}$ when $\Re[s]>1$ (and to constrain piecewise solutions which just use the standard definition in this region, you should also need to be able to show that it is a reasonable extension in some way, i.e. continuity or analyticity).

My current best bet is the Laruent expansion about the pole at $s=1$ (in terms of Stieltjes constants):

$$\zeta(s)=\frac1{s-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(s-1)^n}{n!}\!\!\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{(\ln k)^n}k-\frac{(\ln m)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]$$

However, I was unable to find a proof online of the equality of this expression to the standard one, and I expect the proof to be rather involved. Does anyone have any suggestions for more workable formulas for $\zeta(s)$?

Comment: Related, but without proofs: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267432

Comment: @ccorn I like the accepted answer there. It would be fantastic if someone could reference a proof for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the accepted answer for [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267432) and following [Gerry Myerson's answer elsewhere](http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.math/2006-04/msg01053.html), I found [Sondow's paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1994-120-02/S0002-9939-1994-1172954-7/home.html).

Answer (score 2):

A recent paper [EULER’S CONSTANT: EULER’S WORK AND MODERN DEVELOPMENTS](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.1856v6.pdf) of JEFREY C. LAGARIAS, has the derivation of your stated expression for Riemann's zeta function. See page 32.

Comment: This is a nice proof. Both this and ccorn's answer give proofs that the respective formulas are equal to the "conventional" zeta function on $\Re\,s>1$ (which is of course all we can hope for). But how would we prove that the two formulas are equal to each other on the rest of the plane?

Comment: (I guess this follows from the fact that both functions are analytic, but I'm looking for a less high-powered algebraic explanation.)