# Convergence of Euler-transformed zeta series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

I am trying to prove that the expression

$$(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{(-1)^m}{2^{n+1}}{n\choose m}(m+1)^{-s}$$

converges to an analytic continuation of the alternating zeta function for all $s\in\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}$, following [the paper by Sondow](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1994-120-02/S0002-9939-1994-1172954-7/home.html).

My strategy is to show that this "Euler transformation" of the original series,

$$(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}n^{-s},$$

which is convergent for $\Re s>0$, can be achieved by repeatedly applying the transformation

$$a_1-a_2+a_3-\dots=\frac12a_1+\frac12[(a_1-a_2)-(a_2-a_3)+(a_3-a_4)-\cdots],$$

which after $k$ transformations extends the region of convergence to $\Re s>-k$, so that the limit sequence is convergent everywhere. The general term after $k$ transformations of the alternating zeta function is:

$$(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{(-1)^m}{2^{n+1}}{n\choose m}(m+1)^{-s}+\frac1{2^k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^{n+m-1}{k\choose m}(m+n)^{-s}$$

Now it follows from the alternating series test that for $k=0$, the original series is convergent for $\Re s>0$, but in order to apply the alternating series test on the transformed series, I need to know that

$$\sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^{m-1}{k\choose m}(m+n)^{-s}\ge0\tag{1}$$
$$\sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^{m-1}{k\choose m}(m+n+1)^{-s}\le\sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^{m-1}{k\choose m}(m+n)^{-s}.\tag{2}$$

Now $(1)$ for $k$ follows from $(2)$ for $k-1$, but verifying $(2)$ is not at all obvious to me. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Note: this is a continuation of [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575455/a-convergent-everywhere-expression-for-zetas-for-all-1-ne-s-in-bbb-c-with?rq=1).

Comment: The answer to this question follows from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896414/deltakn-alpha-converges-monotonically-to-zero-when-alphak?lq=1 which I asked after being stymied by the lack of response to this one, easy rep for anyone who wants the bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Note:* According to OPs comment the answer he is interested in is already given in the [predecessor question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896414/deltakn-alpha-converges-monotonically-to-zero-when-alphak?lq=1).
>
> In order to provide some additional information here's a different approach following the reference stated in the *[paper by J. Sondow](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1994-120-02/S0002-9939-1994-1172954-7/S0002-9939-1994-1172954-7.pdf)*. In fact this answer addresses only a specific aspect of OPs question.

J. Sondow states in section 2 that *any* converging series $A$ of complex numbers, written with alternating signs has following representation
\begin{align*}
A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}a_n=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{\Delta^j a_1}{2^{j+1}}+
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\Delta^k a_n}{2^k},\tag{1}
\end{align*}
where $\Delta^0 a_n=a_n$ and
\begin{align*}
\Delta^k a_n=\Delta^{k-1}a_n-\Delta^{k-1}a_{n+1}=\sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^m\binom{k}{m}a_{n+m},
\end{align*}
for $k\geq 1$. He continues that in *[Theory and Application of Infinite Series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486661652)* by Konrad Knopp it is proved, that the sum of the last series in (1) approaches $0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$, so that
\begin{align*}
A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}a_n=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{\Delta^j a_1}{2^{j+1}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
which is *[Euler's transformation of series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration)*.

> **Proof of Euler's transformation of series:** based upon *K. Knopp, § $33B$*
>
> In order to proof this statement we consider more generally a convergent series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{(k)}$ with each of its terms is expressed, *in any manner* as the sum of an infinite series:
>
> \begin{align*}
> (A)\quad\begin{cases}
> z^{(0)}&=a_0^{(0)}+a_1^{(0)}+\cdots+a_n^{(0)}+\cdots\\
> z^{(1)}&=a_0^{(1)}+a_1^{(1)}+\cdots+a_n^{(1)}+\cdots\\
> &\cdots\\
> z^{(k)}&=a_0^{(k)}+a_1^{(k)}+\cdots+a_n^{(k)}+\cdots\\
> &\cdots\\
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> We shall assume further that the vertical columns in this array *themselves constitute convergent series*, and denote their sums by $s^{(0)},s^{(1)},\ldots,s^{(n)},\ldots$
>
> *Question:* Under what conditions may the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^{(n)}$$ formed by these numbers be expected to converge, with
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{(k)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^{(n)}$$
>
> *Note:* Knopp uses $z$ to denote *Zeilen*, the german word for *rows* and he uses $s$ to denote *Spalten*, the german word for columns.

Knopp then shows a far-reaching theorem originally proved by *A. Markoff*:

> **Markoff's transformation of series:**
>
> Let a convergent series $A=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{(k)}$ be given with each of its terms itself expressed as a convergent series:
>   $$z^{(k)}=a_0^{(k)}+a_1^{(k)}+\cdots+a_n^{(k)}+\cdots\qquad k\geq 0$$
>   Let the individual columns $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_n^{(k)}$ of the array $(A)$ so formed represent convergent series with sums $s^{(n)}, n\geq 0$, so that the remainders
>   $$r_m^{(k)}=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_n^{(k)}\qquad\qquad m\geq 0$$
>   of the series in the horizontal rows also constitute a convergent series
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r_m^{(k)}=R_m\qquad\qquad m \text{ fixed}.$$
>
> In order that the sums by vertical columns should form a convergent series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^{(n)}$, it is necessary and sufficient that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}R_m=R$ should exist; and in order that the relation
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{(k)}$$
>   should hold as well, it is necessary and sufficient that this limit $R$ should be $0$.

*Note:* Observe, that in Markoff's theorem *no absolute convergence* is required, making this theorem far-reaching and flexible.

With the help of *Markoff's transformation of series* Knopp then proves *Euler's transformation of series* as follows:

> In the array $(A)$ we substitute for $a_n^{(k)}$:
>   \begin{align*}
> a_n^{(k)}=(-1)^k\left[\frac{1}{2^n}\Delta^na_k-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\Delta^{n+1}a_k\right]\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>   If we now sum for every $n$, keeping $k$ fixed (i.e. form the sum of the $k^{th}$ horizontal row) we obtain
>   $$z^{(k)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^{(k)}=(-1)^k\frac{1}{2^0}\Delta^0a_k=(-1)^ka_k\qquad\qquad k\text{ fixed}.$$
>
> *Note:* We thereby used following property of a series: If a series $A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ is given with $a_n=x_n-x_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\xi$, then
>   \begin{align*}
> A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n=x_0-\xi\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> For
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\Delta^na_k}{2^n}=
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\binom{n}{0}a_k-\binom{n}{1}a_{k+1}+-\cdot+(-1)^n\binom{n}{n}a_{n+k}}{2^n}$$
>   is equal to zero, because $a_k,-a_{k+1},a_{k+2},\ldots$ form a null sequence.
>
> Accordingly (3) gives an expression for the individual terms of the given series $\sum(-1)^ka_k$ in infinite series. Forming the sum of the $n^{th}$ column, we obtain the series
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left[\frac{1}{2^n}\Delta^na_k-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\Delta^{n+1}a_k\right]\qquad\qquad n\text{ fixed}$$
>   the generic term of this series, as
>   $\Delta^{n+1}a_k=\Delta^na_k-\Delta^na_{k+1}$, can be written in the form
>   $$\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{n+1}}\left[\Delta^na_k+\Delta^na_{k+1}\right]
> =\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\left[(-1)^k\Delta^na_k-(-1)^{k+1}\Delta^na_{k+1}\right],$$
>   so that the series under consideration may again be summed directly, by (4). We obtain
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_n^{(k)}=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\left[\Delta^na_0-\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(-1)^k\Delta^na_k\right]\qquad\qquad k\text{ fixed.}$$
>
> Since, however, the numbers $a_k$ form a null sequence, so do the first differences and the $n^{th}$ differences generally, for any fixed $n$. The vertical columns are thus seen to constitute convergent series of sums
>   $$s^{(n)}=\frac{\Delta^na_0}{2^{n+1}}.$$
>
> The validity of Euler's transformation will accordingly be established, when we have shown that $R_m\rightarrow0$. Now the horizontal remainders are seen to have the values
>   $$r_m^{(k)}=(-1)^k\frac{\Delta^ma_k}{2^m,}$$
>   following precisely the same line of argument as was above for the entire horizontal rows. Thus
>   $$R_m=\frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\Delta^ma_k\qquad\qquad m\text{ fixed.}$$
>   If we write for brevity $(-1)^k(a_k-a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}-+\cdots)=r_k$, this series for $R_m$ may be thought of as obtained by term-by-term addition from the $(m+1)$ series:
>   $$r_0,\binom{m}{1}r_1,\binom{m}{2}r_2,\ldots,\binom{m}{m}r_m.$$
>   Hence
>   $$R_m=\frac{r_0+\binom{m}{1}r_1+\binom{m}{2}r_2+\cdots+\binom{m}{m}r_m}{2^m}$$
>   therefore, as $r_m$ is the term of a null sequence, so is $R_m$ and this proves the validity of *Euler's transformation* with full generality.

Comment: Very nice. I have a few questions: What is meant by "null sequence"? Is that a sequence whose terms are all equal to $0$? You remark that I am looking for a proof of Euler's transformation, but I think that my goal is a bit different since the usual statement shows that the transformed series is convergent to the same number as the original series if it is convergent, while I am trying to verify convergence in a region where the original series is no longer valid, with no concern (for the present purpose) of what number in fact it converges to.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro:First the easy one: A *null sequence* is a sequence converging to zero (used here as necessary condition for a series to converge). I have two versions of K.Knopp's book, the german version and also an english translation. The english translation uses the term *null sequence* which is in fact a verbatim translation of the german term "Nullfolge". Regarding your other remark: I'm aware what you want to show (interesting). Maybe I've missed the point you have written in the comment. But I thought with respect to the predecessor question you have pointed to, (tbc.)

Comment: (cont.) you are specifically interested in one aspect of your question. Namely $(2)$ on p. 422 in J. Sondows paper . Since from (2) it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\Delta^ka_n}{2^k}$ approaches $0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$. J. Sondow refers for a proof of this aspect to K. Knopp §33B, which is the main part of my answer. (Btw I've weakened my statement regarding your question in my answer. Hopefully this is more in your line). Best regards,

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Thanks for accepting the answer and granting the bounty! Best regards,